# Can insecure data storage vulnerability be exploited without root access?

Tags: android, security, storage

I'm currently writing an essay about Android vulnerabilities, and I've came across the insecure data storage vulnerability. I'm pretty new to this topic, an although I have read a lot of posts and articles and saw many videos, one thing keeps me uncertain. If an app suffers from such a vulnerability, e.g. is storing sensitive data in plain text in `shared preferences` or XML files, can those files be accessed without having the phone rooted/jailbroken? By now I assume they cannot, nonetheless I haven't found any explicit proof that it's true.

I'm sorry for asking maybe a little dumb question, but I appreciate any kind answers or help.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared preferences are xml files stored in the app's storage area with permissions to only let the linux level user read/write them.  Every app on Android is its own linux level user.  So no, short of root or an exploit, it shouldn't be possible to read a shared preference.  (Exception-  globally read/writable shared preferences used to be possible, if you explicitly used that.  But it was never suggested).

That said-  you can't assume the user won't root your phone.  Or that the OS isn't an AOSP variant that breaks things purposely.  So if you wouldn't trust the user with a piece of data, you shouldn't trust shared preferences with it.  But it is safe to say another app can't access it without root or a privelidge exploit.

Comment: Big thanks, this pretty much answers my question. One more little question, if an app has any other vulnerability that provides access to app data and the attacker manages to exploit it, he should be able to read it even if the phone isn't rooted. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if an app has an exploit that allows code execution or t allows the attacker to read its files, then any file it has access to would be compromised.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: It can be in one scenario when the backup is enabled, for example check here https://medium.com/@rickbuiten/how-to-hack-the-android-auto-backup-for-apps-functionality-8eb0ce3290a8

Comment: Woah, I didn't know about that one. Thank you!